# How to build this program without using global variables?

Tags: python, function, variables, global

I just created my first Python project. I'm sure there's a lot of improvements that could be made, but I have one specific question about how to alter my code.

I've been reading that it's unwise to use global variables (due to security concerns). But I'm not sure how to make multiple functions work together (i.e. use the same variables) unless they are global.

The program below does three things:

1. Generate a password.
2. Encrypt that password.
3. Decrypt the password.

However, I only declared global variables in part 2 to encrypt the password.

My question is: how do alter the code to avoid using globals? I've pasted all the code below for reference, but the globals are declared in `def listToString()` and `def passEncryptor():`.

```
import random

#variables to hold a list and a string
Password = []
Encrypted = ''

#variables to hold the specific characters
#to use in creating the password
a = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
b = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
c = '0123456789'
d = '!@#$%^&*()'

#variable holds all possible values
#that could be found in the password
e = a + b + c + d

#variables will randomize the password length
sm = random.randint(2,3)
lg = random.randint(3,4)

#function generates a randomized password
def passwordGenerator() :

    #append elements from variables a - d
    #to the Password variable
    for x in range(sm) :
        Password.append(random.choice(a))
    for x in range(sm) :
        Password.append(random.choice(b))
    for x in range(lg) :
        Password.append(random.choice(c))
    for x in range(sm) :
        Password.append(random.choice(d))

    #randomize the order of the elements    
    random.shuffle(Password)

    #ensure the first element is a letter
    Password.insert(0, random.choice(a))

    #print to show that the program worked
    print(Password)

#call function to generate a randomized password
passwordGenerator()

#function to store 5 random elements in a string
def listToString() :

    #can't seem to get this to work
    #without using a global variable
    global rand5
    rand5 = ''
    x = random.choices(e, k=5)
    for val in x :
        rand5 += val
    return rand5

#for each element in the password
#add the random 5 elements from listToString()
def passEncryptor():

    global tempPass
    tempPass = ''
    for val in Password :

        #gets 5 new random elements
        listToString()

        #concatenate the random elements
        #with the real password
        tempPass += val + rand5

    print(tempPass)
passEncryptor()

#function to unencrypt an encrypted password
def passDecryptor():

    #convert the encrypted string to a list
    encryptedList = []
    for val in tempPass :
        encryptedList.append(val)

    #remove the random 5 elements    
    decrypt = encryptedList[::6]
    decrypted = ''
    #convert back to a string
    for val in decrypt :
        decrypted += val

    print(decrypted)

passDecryptor()
```

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Also look  up common methods for avoiding globals, and refer to your *remaining* problem in your question.

Comment: define these global variables at top of the program one way, if you don't define them they will run fine, use assignment operator to save output of function eg  passs = encrpt()

Comment: Using global variables, has long been [considered harmful](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesConsideredHarmful) for a variety of reasons not necessarily just security issues. Two major ones are it makes code harder to debug and maintain.

Comment: A very good and common way to avoid global variables is by following the OOP ([Object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)) paradigm, which Python fully supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it really just comes down to lack of knowledge - you aren't taking advantage of function parameters - I'm assuming you don't know what those are, because if you did, you would prefer them over global variables.

I don't know that "security" is exactly what you're sacrificing when using global variables. Sure, I can think of hypothetical examples, and I'm sure someone can cite some real example(s) where use of global variables was a major security issue... What I mean is, using global variables doesn't make your program intrinsically insecure - it's just that it's very easy to use them incorrectly (is there a correct way?). There are better solutions available to solve the problems you think you can only solve with global variables.

The code you posted actually demonstrates the crux of global variables perfectly - If I, a user of your program, want to generate multiple passwords, the result I get is unexpected:

```
['d', 'q', '3', 'O', 'g', '1', '$', 'J', '&', '7']
dsLT(mq4N^Yy3(L)%iOr&VM3gTfaZq1&ud9B$RJJ1aJe6Nju&O2*rE7Zz@Y!
dq3Og1$J&7
>>> passwordGenerator()
['n', '&', 'E', ')', '7', '0', '&', 'O', '2', '1', '$', '3', 'q', 'q', 'k', 'J', 'B', '1', 'd', 'g']
>>> passwordGenerator()
['j', '9', 'd', '1', 'k', 'O', 'B', 'q', 'Q', '2', 'g', 'o', 'e', '7', '1', 'n', 'q', '$', 'J', '&', '!', '0', 'A', '!', 'E', ')', '3', '7', '&', '2']
>>> passwordGenerator()
['u', 'o', '!', ')', '0', 'j', 'h', '1', '!', 'q', '7', 'g', '$', '9', 'n', 'k', 'q', '1', '&', 'd', 'J', '2', 'B', '8', '3', '2', '&', '7', 'L', '*', 'O', '5', 'Q', 'e', '&', 'S', '2', 'E', 'A', 'x']
>>> passwordGenerator()
['o', 'h', 'u', '1', 'S', 'q', '&', '7', '$', 'g', '7', '8', '2', '3', 'J', '&', 'k', 'A', '9', 'q', '2', '1', '6', 'B', '0', '*', '&', '!', 'e', 'x', 'j', 'B', 'L', 'a', 'o', '9', ')', '$', 'n', '9', 'U', 's', '!', 'Q', 'E', '2', 'd', '&', '5', 'O']
```

`passwordGenerator` modifies the state of the global variable `Password` by appending elements to it each time the function is invoked. Generally speaking, the function is modifying the state of a variable (which happens to live outside of the scope of the function) unexpectedly. This is why global variables can be a source of problems, whether it's security or otherwise.

This is unrelated, but you're also doing some unnecessary things, like shuffling `Password` after appending random characters to it. Here's what it could look like with function parameters:

```
def get_random_password(alphabet):
    from random import randint, choices

    password_length = randint(5, 16)
    password = choices(alphabet, k=password_length)

    return "".join(password)


def get_encrypted(alphabet, plaintext):
    from random import choices

    return "".join(char + "".join(choices(alphabet, k=5)) for char in plaintext)

def get_decrypted(encrypted_plaintext):
    return encrypted_plaintext[::6]

def main():
    import string

    alphabet = string.digits + string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation
    # alphabet = string.printable.rstrip()

    password = get_random_password(alphabet)
    encrypted = get_encrypted(alphabet, password)
    decrypted = get_decrypted(encrypted)

    print(f"The password is \"{password}\"")
    print(f"Encrypted: \"{encrypted}\"")
    print(f"Decrypted: \"{decrypted}\"")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
The password is "O*L7~"
Encrypted: "OiL)V\*I={w&LX5"2-7WF/\+~5%_mP"
Decrypted: "O*L7~"
>>>
```

I've also added an entry point `main` and have taken advantage of the standard library a bit more. This is tangential, but you aren't really "encrypting" the string, strictly speaking - it's more like obfuscation, but whatever.

Comment: What took me hours took you 10 minutes. Seems I have a lot of growth ahead of me. Thanks for the helpful hint/tips/tricks. Much appreciated your taking the time and effort to write all that out!

Comment: @KyleMarvin Everyone starts somewhere! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) and put yours functions as class methods and variables as member of this class.